# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, python-3.x, django

Hola estoy trabajando en una aplicación web con Django. En uno de mis HTML utilizo una ventana modal que trabajaba perfectamente, el código iba así:

**`index.html`**

```
{% block extrajs %}

<script type="text/javascript">
function abrir_modal_detalle_armario(url) {
    $('#detalle').load(url, function () {
      $(this).modal('show');
    });
  }
</script>

{% endblock extrajs %}
```

En la misma página muestro una tabla y necesito poder ordenar por columnas y fue ahí cuando vino el problema cambié lo que tenia por:

**`index.html`**

```
{% block extrajs%}

<script type="text/javascript">
function abrir_modal_detalle_armario(url) {
    $('#detalle').load(url, function () {
      $(this).modal('show');
    });
  }
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.28.14/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('#mi-tabla').tablesorter();
});
</script>

{% endblock extrajs %}
```

Ahora la tabla ordena perfectamente por las columnas pero dejo de funcionar la ventana modal. ¿Qué puede estar ocurriendo aquí para que me lance el error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function